# Why can't I find SQL Server Management Studio after installation?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

So I downloaded Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 on a new computer I have to be using and when I go to Start -> Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 I don't see SQL Server Management Studio. I followed the step by step installation and configuration. Why can't I find the program? What am I missing?

I can't wait for 3 hours more before answering my own question. I should have been asleep hours ago. Here is the answer:

Thought you guys' comments were really helpful. But the solution I had to find by Google searching around. It appears that SQL Server 2008 R2 can be downloaded with or without the management tools. I honestly have NO IDEA why someone would not want the management tools. But either way, the options are here:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

and the one for 64 bit WITH the management tools (management studio) is here:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

From the first link I presented, the 3rd and 4th include the management studio for 32 and 64 bit respectively.

Guys, thanks a lot for your insight. It was cool to learn that stuff.

Comment: My executable is stored here: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe` - if you look in a similar path can you find the executable?

Comment: When installing, did you install the "Client Tools" feature?? That's the feature the Management Studio is contained in - if you don't install it, you won't have SSMS

Comment: @mwan Thanks for the directory. Very cool. Umm, actually I only saw a couple of dll files. No executable. @ marc, I honestly have no idea if I install the Client Tools feature. I'm going to have to assume not. But it's kinda funny that I had to look out for that at all. I saw a number of tasks the installation was going to go through and I went through them one by one till complete. Don't know how I missed anything. But I guess it's time for another installation.. Thanks!

Comment: Here you will get the ssms : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears that SQL Server 2008 R2 can be downloaded with or without the management tools. I honestly have NO IDEA why someone would not want the management tools. But either way, the options are here:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

and the one for 64 bit WITH the management tools (management studio) is here:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

From the first link I presented, the 3rd and 4th include the management studio for 32 and 64 bit respectively.

Comment: Why might someone not install the tools? Maybe because they are installing it on a server...

Comment: @Andrew Barber Hmm. I didn't think about that possibility...Thanks for the comment, Bro.

Comment: I'm installing it on a server and I DEFINITELY want the tools!

Comment: Man, 4 years old and still dead on. Microsoft should hire you to add explanations to their downloads...

Answer (score 0):

Generally if the installation went smoothly, it will create the desktop icons/folders. Maybe check the installation summary log to see if there's any underlying errors.

It should be located C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log(date stamp)\

Comment: Hey Joey. So I checked it out and found the final result to have passed..

Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Passed
  Exit code (Decimal):           0
  Exit message:                  Passed
  Start time:                    2011-09-23 23:40:09
  End time:                      2011-09-23 23:40:28
  Requested action:              RunRules